# Difference between body.style.backgroundColor and window.getComputedStyle(body).getPropertyValue('background-color')

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the background color of the body, and I am wondering what is the difference between:

`body.style.backgrounColor` and

```
window.getComputedStyle(body).getPropertyValue('background-color')
```

Given that  `var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];`

Is there any other way I can get the background-color?

Comment: could you maybe look at the answers and accept/upvote any good ones? This question has been here for 10 days and there are 3 answers

Answer (score 6):

Using:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor
```

sets the [style](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-style-attribute) directly on an element, or returns the current value of the related style property that has been set through the style attribute or property. Such values are considered by a user agent when determining how to display an element when applying [CSS rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/) (if there are any).

An element's style object does not necessarily reflect values applied to an element through CSS rules, though they may be the same (by chance or deliberately setting both to the same value).

The order in which style rules are applied to an element are listed in the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#value-stages). Rules applied directly to the element are of second highest precedence, after `!important` declarations.

Using:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('background-color')
```

is described in the [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle) specification. Basically, it returns the current style property values being used to display an element based on CSS rules, i.e. what is actually being applied to the element.

This often different to the value of the related style property (which not have a value unless set by a property or attribute).

Comment: So, in order to get the actual current style, I should use getComputedStyle, right?

Comment: Yes, if that's what you want. But it's not supported by all browsers in use, check compatibility tables.

Comment: @HommerSmith I know this answer is years later, but I just ran into a problem relevant to your question and I can tell you in Firefox and Chrome to get CSS values that are actually being applied I had to use getComputedStyle(<element>,null).backgroundColor because <element>.style.backgroundColor just never worked. I was following Lynda JavaScript Essential Training (2011) with Simon Allardice... a bit has changed since then, lol.

Answer (score 3):

just using `body.style.backgroundColor` will only be able to sense if an inline style is on the body and give you that (e.g. a style applied via the `style` attribute in the html or using the `style` property in JavaScript). `getComputedStyle` also gets styles that were applied to it via stylesheets in `<style>` tags, inherited styles from parent elements, and everything.

In short, `body.style.backgroundColor` will get the background color that was in the `style` attribute (`<body style="background-color:red>`) or applied through JavaScript, `getComputedStyle` will also be able to get style from stylesheets (`<style>body{background-color:red}</style>`)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `document.body.style.backgroundColor` will get only `inline` style `property` of an element like this

```
<body style="background-color:red">
```

On the other hand `window.getComputedStyle` will `get` the actual property after `CSS` and styles are applied to the element, for example, this is possible to get using `window.getComputedStyle`

```
body{
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

But it's not possible to read `css` style given above using `document.body.style.backgroundColor`. Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/78t7w/3/). Also, check [this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/styles-and-classes-getcomputedstyle).

Answer (score -1):

If you have

```
background-color: red !important;
```

anywhere in your .css files, or `<style>` elements, that will override inline style e.g. `style="background-color: blue;"`