# Best way to change background color with JavaScript HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, css

What is the most appropriate and cross-browser compatible way to change background color of an element using JavaScript?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="head1" style="background-color:red">This is a heading</h1>

<script>

// this one?
document.getElementById("head1").style["background-color"] = "yellow"; 

// this one?
document.getElementById("head1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

//or this one?
document.getElementById("head1").style.background = "yellow";

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: research : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943118/difference-between-body-style-backgroundcolor-and-window-getcomputedstylebody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better method if you are using CSS `class` instead of using `style`.

```js
function foo(){
  document.getElementById("head1").className = "newclass";
  }
```

```css
h1{background:gold;}
h1.newclass{background:green;}
```

```html
<h1 id="head1">This is a heading</h1>
<button onclick="foo()">Click!</button>
```

Comment: If my answer suits your requirements than you may accept this answer. It's better because instead of inline element we are using classes here.

Answer (score 3):

Get the element, then use the `.style` attribute along with the `.backgroundColor` attribute to change it:

```js
function foo(){
  document.getElementById("head1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="head1" style="background-color:red">This is a heading</h1>
<button onclick="foo()">Click!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thus, your 2<sup>nd</sup> option is the right one.