# How to change color of font-awesome icon by clicking the icon

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

```js
var garbage = document.getElementById("garbage");

garbage.addEventListener("click",function(){
  garbage.style.color = "#66c144";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="garbage">
  <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
</div>
```

Hi, I am trying to change the font color for font-awesome trash icon by clicking the icon. However, it is not working. I would appreciate any tips on how to get this work.

---

```js
var trash = document.getElementById("trash"),
    glass = document.getElementById("glass"),
    organic = document.getElementById("organic"),
    plastic = document.getElementById("plastic"),
    paper = document.getElementById("paper");

trash.addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.children[0].style.color = "#66c144";
    glass.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    organic.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    plastic.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    paper.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
});

glass.addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.children[0].style.color = "#66c144";
    trash.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    organic.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    plastic.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    paper.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    
});

organic.addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.children[0].style.color = "#66c144";
    trash.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    glass.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    plastic.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    paper.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    
});

plastic.addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.children[0].style.color = "#66c144";
    trash.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    glass.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    organic.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    paper.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
});

paper.addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.children[0].style.color = "#66c144";
    trash.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    glass.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    organic.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
    plastic.children[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

          <div class="icons flex">
                <div id="trash">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i> 
                </div>    
                <div id="glass">
                    <i class="fas fa-wine-glass"></i>
                </div>
                <div id="organic">
                    <i class="fab fa-envira"></i>
                </div>
                <div id="plastic">
                    <i class="far fa-hdd"></i>
                </div>    
                <div id="paper">
                    <i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>
                </div>    
          </div>
```

**UPDATE**
So Thanks to everyone's help, I managed to get the result I wanted (Every time I click a different icon, only the icon I click has the different color). On top of that, I am curious if there is a less repetitive or messy way to execute what I have now like using "Function" or something. I would appreciate if I can get some tips on it.

Comment: you have to chang the i color not the div

Comment: This code has syntax errors. In addition, your class name is `fas` which should be `fa` if I remember correctly. At last, you're styling the div instead of the i element, which probably gets overwritten.

Comment: @Roberrrt Op is using Font Awesome 5, that has the `fas` prefix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to change background color with JavaScript HTML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115780/best-way-to-change-background-color-with-javascript-html-dom)

Comment: @MatheusCuba Ah, I see!

Comment: _“However, the JavaScript DOM does not allow me to put "id" inside the font-awesome class”_ - really, how? Sounds more like “I couldn’t get it to work”, to be honest ... and in that regard, please go read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Cbroe To be more specific of that meaning, what I meant was "id" does not work/function if it is inside fontawsome <i> tag.

Comment: ... which is probably still nonsense. Unless you show us what exactly “didn’t work”, we can only tell you that you most likely did something wrong.

Comment: @YongJunJung you should roll back to the original question otherwise if someone reads it as it is right now, they may not understand what was wrong in the first place. The context can be totally misinterpreted. You should add your solution to the original question and title that part and maybe separate it with a `<hr>`

Comment: The [**second article**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) would be optimal for that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some other options to change an FA icon. The keyword `this` represents `garbage`. The `.property` or `.method()/.function()` references the icon.

#### References

[**.children**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

[**.querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

[**.getElementsByTagName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

[**.classList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

[**.firstElementChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)

---

#### Demo

```js
var garbage = document.getElementById("garbage");

garbage.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.children[0].style.color = "#66c144";
  this.querySelector('.fas').style.fontSize = '3rem';
  this.getElementsByTagName('I')[0].classList.toggle('fa-spin');
  this.firstElementChild.style.transition = 'color 1.5s ease 1.25s, font-size 0.75s ease-out';
}, false);
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="garbage">
  <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG you are a life saver. I have to get used to using all those methods. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's great, I was going to add another way of referencing by Event Object but I was worried it might be confusing. If you are interested in using `event.target` as a reference read this **[article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/event_capturing_bubbling_javascript.htm)** and when you get the gist of events, then read this **[one](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)**

Comment: Luckily, I was able to grasp the concept. I did not understand 100% yet such as the "false" part (I guess this stops the icon from spinning?). event.target seems super useful as it helped me solve "How to remove objects" problem last time. I will read it; also I have updated my final result but could you take a look if there is a less redundant way to this? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @YongJunJung the false part is deceiving, it's the 3rd optional parameter of `addEventListener()` by default it is false. When false the eventListener will invoke callback during the bubbling phase (after the target phase, like click or hover -- it's very short). True means callback function will be invoked on capture phase (before target phase). Capture phase is rarely used, the only time I find it useful is dealing with key events (keyup, keydown). What makes the icon stop spinning is that it's a class being toggled, `fa-spin` is a FA special class.

Comment: See my comment in main post, and also you should make another post about your next question otherwise the moderators will gripe about multiple questions on your post.

Comment: Hmmm..I kinda of get it. Boolean still confuses me. Oh I see, I did not know how powerful font-awesome was till I used it. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the `);` after the closing `}`:

```js
var garbage = document.getElementById("garbage");

garbage.addEventListener("click",function(){
  garbage.style.color = "#66c144";
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="garbage">
  <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
</div>
```

*Note:* You don't need to *target* the *parent*, you can just give the `id` to the icon.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing parenthesis after your event listener:

```
var garbage = document.getElementById("garbage");

garbage.addEventListener("click",function(){
    garbage.style.color = "#66c144";
});
```

Comment: I'm seriously being downvoted when I posted the exact same answer a minute before the other guy? Incredible

Comment: Thank you. Ha that is not fair!

Comment: I gave you +1, but you probably edited it in under < 5min, won't say for sure. Would be strange to get 2 downvotes only because there's no snipper, unlikely.

Comment: @VXp Sam Littlefair didn't edit it, there's no link to the left of the avatar and he answered 1 minute before you. Regardless, I upped both of you. Mr. Littlefair for answering correctly and you for answering correctly with a [mcve].

Comment: @zer00ne Returned the "favor" because of the useful additional info and good answer overall. I know, that's why I wrote "under 5min", because if you do it inside that time frame, link doesn't appear. I think he did, otherwise why would he get -2.

Comment: @VXp Not aware of the under 5 min editing window, good to know, thanks. Not sure why the -2, there's another deleted answer that was downvoted yet it is identical to your answer except it lacked the `<link>` which is probably why when tested it looked wrong.

Comment: @zer00ne Np m8, yea, most likely because of that.