# Changing color of Font Awesome icon on click: CSS / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, font-awesome

Forgive me in advance if I'm being stupid here but I'm trying to change the color of 3 Font Awesome icons from white to black when a menu is clicked on my site using JavaScript to add a class of "active" on top of the current class of "social-icon" so that the CSS is activated.

I'm using a div called 'toggle' as a navbar and currently only the first icon is changed to black when this is clicked. I've tried using querySelectorAll instead but that doesn't work and I've also tried moving the social-icon class to within the font awesome icon class but again nothign. I'm just curious at to where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

JS

```
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle')
const showcase = document.querySelector('.showcase')
const socialToggle = document.querySelector('.social-icon')

menuToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menuToggle.classList.toggle('active')
    showcase.classList.toggle('active')
    socialToggle.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

CSS

```
.social {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 18px;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.social li {
    list-style: none;
}

.social-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    margin-right: 25px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-size: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.social-icon.active {
color: black;
}
```

HTML

```
            <div class="toggle"></div>


<ul class="social">
            <li class="social-icon"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li>
            <li class="social-icon"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
            <li class="social-icon"><i class="fab fa-tiktok"></i></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: querySelector returns one element

Comment: you can take a look here it will help you : [How to change color of font-awesome icon by clicking the icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49856171/how-to-change-color-of-font-awesome-icon-by-clicking-the-icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to get a node list with all the icons and then iterate them:

```
const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
const showcase = document.querySelector('.showcase');
const socialToggle = document.querySelectorAll('.social-icon');

menuToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
    showcase.classList.toggle('active');
    socialToggle.forEach(function(el) {
        el.classList.toggle('active');
    });
})
```