# Two ways to get background-color property using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, properties

There are two ways to obtain the `background-color` property using Javascript:

- `var bcolor = window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("background-color");`
- `var bcolor = elem.style.backgroundColor;`

What's the difference between them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between body.style.backgroundColor and window.getComputedStyle(body).getPropertyValue('background-color')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943118/difference-between-body-style-backgroundcolor-and-window-getcomputedstylebody)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-window-getcomputedstyle-method/)

The getComputedStyle() method is used to get all the computed CSS property and values of the specified element. The use of computed style is displaying the element after stylings from multiple sources have been applied. The getComputedStyle() method returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object.

In other words, the returned value from both calls can be different, since the computed style will be the result of applying all rules for the element. 
The element CSS reads what we set directly on the element, which can be overwritten by another rule on another element (its parent for example).

Comment: Also, if I understood it correctly from reading of other articles, the `elem.style.backgroundColor` won't work if the property was set by CSS. So, that method is good only for properties set inline (inside the HTML elements).