# Can you move a div with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to learn the absolute basics of game-making, and I'm wondering why I can move an img but not a div element.
JS:

```
var element;
function moveSelection(evt) {
  element = document.getElementById("char");
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) - 10;
      break;
    case 39:
       element.style.left = parseInt(element.style.left) + 10;
       break;
    case 38:
       element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) - 10;
       break;
    case 40:
       element.style.top = parseInt(element.style.top) + 10;
       break;
   }
}
window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
```

Now, if I have an img tag with the id of char, I can move it with my arrow keys.

```
<img src="" id="char">
```

But if I remove that image and replace it with a div,

```
<div id="char"></div>
```

it doesn't let me move it.

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't seem to work with either image or div tags...

Comment: @NickParsons, it works in the thing I'm using. Go to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GDFB5WH621FJ) page, hit run, click in the box on the left, and then you should be able to move the image with arrowkeys.

Comment: @TorNato (sorry for the offtopic but) w3schools is still at this day the worst place you could learn web development.

Comment: Okay. I just picked a random one. What would you suggest? @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: @TorNato `element.style.*` will give you the styles defined in the `style` attribute. Are you removing the `style` attribute when you use the div?

Comment: @TorNato also make sure you define `'px'` as the unit. `(parseInt(element.style.left) - 10) + 'px'`

Comment: Nope. Divs still have the style attribute though, so why would that change anything? I've tried it (e.g: element.left = parseInt(element.left) - 10) but it does nothing.

Comment: Still doesn't work, @NickParsons. (E.G: element.left = parseInt(element.left) - 10 + "px") Also doesn't work when I do element.left = (parseInt(element.left) - 10) + "px", with brackets

Comment: Works for me if I change the `<img>` to `<div id="char" src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/rocket-ship-png-3.png" style="position:absolute;left:0; top:0; border: 1px solid black" height="200" width="200">asdf</div>`

Comment: @TorNato seems to work if I add 'px' and position absolute: https://jsfiddle.net/f5r8zqh6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the code and I'm not sure how it could work with images.

For this to work, a few things need to be done:

1. Ensure the target element's CSS has the [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) property set. You can also use `relative`, `fixed` or `sticky` depending on need.
2. Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead of accessing `style` directly. The `style` property will only contain values [set by a property or attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19943357/6243352).
3. Append a measurement unit like `"px"` to the parsed number.

Here's a minimal, complete example:

```js
const element = document.getElementById("char");
const charStyle = getComputedStyle(element);

function moveSelection(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      element.style.left = parseInt(charStyle.left) - 10 + "px";
      break;
    case 39:
      element.style.left = parseInt(charStyle.left) + 10 + "px";
      break;
    case 38:
      element.style.top = parseInt(charStyle.top) - 10 + "px";
      break;
    case 40:
      element.style.top = parseInt(charStyle.top) + 10 + "px";
      break;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", moveSelection);
```

```css
#char {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="char"></div>
```

Having said that, this sort of design should strike you as an antipattern because it serializes and de-serializes attributes from DOM elements. This is a poor substitute for creating a good old fashioned data structure like:

```
const character = {x: 0, y: 0, stepSize: 10 /*... more properties ...*/};
```

Also, having the keyboard directly triggering the character's movement causes awkward retriggering and generally unreliable UX. It's best to use an animation loop like [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for such cases. The keyboard handler will flip on and off flags for each key but won't actually update anything directly. The animation loop will handle the repositioning smoothly. Your JS script will keep game/animation state and only dump it to the DOM as a decoupled view when it's time to render a frame. This way, data flows in one direction and your app will be easier to write and maintain.